# keyboard emulator device behavior on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, device-driver

I'm building a device driver of sorts that consumes data from a keyboard emulating device.

The device is a card swipe, so its behavior is as follows:

- User walks up, swipes card
- I get a string of characters (key codes, really, including modifier keys for capital letters)
- I don't know how many characters I'm going to get
- I don't know when I'm getting something

Since I don't know how many characters I'm going to get, blocking reads on the keyboard tty aren't useful - I'd end up blocking after the last character. What I'm doing is, in Ruby, using the IO module to perform async reads against the keyboard device, and using a timeout to determine that the end of data was reached. This works fine logically (even a user swiping his or her card fast will do so slower than the send rate between characters).

The issue is that sometimes, I lose data from the middle of the string. My hunch is that there's some sort of buffer overflow happening because I'm reading the data too slowly. Trying to confirm this, I inserted small waits in between each key process. Longer waits (20ms+) do exacerbate the problem. However, a wait of around 5ms actually makes it go away? The only explanation I can come up with is that the async read itself is expensive (because Ruby), and doing them without a rate limit is actually slower than doing them *with* a 5ms delay.

Does this sound rational? Are there other ideas on what this could be?

The ruby is actually JRuby 9000. The machine is Ubuntu LTS 16.

*Edit: here's a snippet of the relevant code*

```
  private def read_swipe(buffer_size, card_reader_input, pause_between_reads, seconds_to_complete)
    limit = Time.now + seconds_to_complete.seconds
    swipe_data = ''
    begin
      start_time = Time.now
      sleep pause_between_reads
      batch = card_reader_input.read_nonblock(buffer_size)
      swipe_data << batch
    rescue IO::WaitReadable
      IO.select([card_reader_input], nil, nil, 0.5)
      retry unless limit < start_time
    end while start_time < limit
    swipe_data
  end
```

where `card_reader_input = File.new(event_handle, 'rb')`

Comment: can you show some of your code to get a better idea

Comment: @maxpleaner done

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Ruby code but you can use `linux sysfs` to access the characters coming out of keyboard 'like' device, and if feasible you can call `C` code from ruby application. I had done this for barcode reader and following is the code:

```
static int init_barcode_com(char* bcr_portname)
{
    int fd;

    /* Open the file descriptor in non-blocking mode */
    fd = open(bcr_portname, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    cout << "Barcode Reader FD: " << fd <<endl;
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open fd for barcode communication with error " << fd <<endl;
    }

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    /* Set up the control structure */
    struct termios toptions;

    /* Get currently set options for the tty */
    tcgetattr(fd, &toptions);

    /* Set custom options */

    /* 9600 baud */
    cfsetispeed(&toptions, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&toptions, B9600);
    /* 8 bits, no parity, no stop bits */
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    toptions.c_cflag |= CS8;
    /* no hardware flow control */
    toptions.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    /* enable receiver, ignore status lines */
    toptions.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
    /* disable input/output flow control, disable restart chars */
    toptions.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    /* disable canonical input, disable echo,
     * disable visually erase chars,
     * disable terminal-generated signals */
    toptions.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    /* disable output processing */
    toptions.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* wait for n (in our case its 1) characters to come in before read returns */
    /* WARNING! THIS CAUSES THE read() TO BLOCK UNTIL ALL */
    /* CHARACTERS HAVE COME IN! */
    toptions.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    /* no minimum time to wait before read returns */
    toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 100;

    /* commit the options */
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions);

    /* Wait for the Barcode to reset */
    usleep(10*1000);

    return fd;
}

static int read_from_barcode_reader(int fd, char* bcr_buf)
{
    int i = 0, nbytes = 0;
    char buf[1];

    /* Flush anything already in the serial buffer */
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);

    while (1) {
        nbytes = read(fd, buf, 1);           // read a char at a time
        if (nbytes == -1) {
            return -1;                       // Couldn't read
        }
        if (nbytes == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (buf[0] == '\n' || buf[0] == '\r') {
            return 0;
        }
        bcr_buf[i] = buf[0];
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now that you do not know how many characters your going to get you can use `VMIN` and `VTIME` combination to address your concern. This [document](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html) details various possibilities with `VMIN` and `VTIME`.